# Beast Shape and other polymorphic spells/abilities and improved unarmed strike

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, polymorph

When you Beast Shape/Elemental Body/Plant Shape/wild shape, how do you know if that form can take advantage of the feat “Improved unarmed strike”?

Or since the feat has no prerequisites do all forms now have an unarmed strike, even if they have no limbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from CRB p182:

> Unarmed Attacks: Striking for damage with punches, kicks, and head butts is much like attacking with a melee weapon, except for the following:...

Note the inclusion of head butts on the list. A body slam from a creature not using an actual slam natural weapon would also reasonably fall into this category. Thus, even for creatures that do have limbs, unarmed strikes are not particularly dependent on those limbs, so a creature without limbs should likewise be able to make them.